# Why does html Input form conflicts to d3 force layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Generally:

I'm trying to get value from input form and pass in to array(nodes[]) connected with force layout graph

Question:

When adding the only form it goes editable

```
d3.select('body').append('input')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uohc4w8p/

But when appending graph, it stops listening keyboard

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/FullName/9nekhp6a/

Could you tell, what's the type of behavior input form shows, and the reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your `keydown` function. You are calling there to `d3.event.preventDefault();`

That prevents all the key events from being send to any other element in the window when you use that function this way:

```
d3.select(window)
 .on('keydown', keydown)
 .on('keyup', keyup);
```

The window receives the event first and prevents the `keydown` event from being propagated to any other element, including `input` element.

If you remove the `d3.event.preventDefault();` line, the input will work again.

Comment: Thanks, man!
May be you know some d3 debug techs to catch/understand such issues?

Comment: Or strong experience is the only way?

Comment: @J.Doe I have never used d3. The shortest path to this type of error is try to show something on console. I registered an event listener to the input for the `keypress` event. Then when the listener wasn't triggered, that gave me the clue.

Comment: Thank you. I've made this, and It didn't triggered.

`document.getElementById("myform").addEventListener('keydown',   function(event) {alert('Undo!')})`

but there's no error at console(because it's not an error). 
I believed, that form could answer smth like 'I was blocked by that line'